# How to kill Grelod the Kind secretly?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I enter at night, I sneak to where Grelod the Kind is sleeping, kill her by one shot -- and somehow Constance Michel notices this in her room with locked doors, and afterwards runs across the orphanage scared, telling me she yields and cannot be calmed.

This is not the way of a good assassination.

How can I kill Grelod the Kind without anybody noticing?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible, several people note how messy you were here later in the game. As a sidenote, it's not needed either. No-one outside the house notices it was you; no-one inside reports you (the kids rejoice even).

Comment: I killed her and left the house before anyone else reacted or was even in my line of sight. If that didn't do it, it's most likely not possible.

Comment: Ha, just for the people saying, "Make sure to kill her with one hit!", she's only got 1 health.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Its not necessary as you do not receive any bounty for the murder even if you just walk up to her and stab her in the face.  She's well known for being cruel to children so everyone sort of looks the other way.

I poisoned her to death and Michel still reacted in the same way, so I think its most likely scripted.

Comment: Agreed... Seems like sloppy scripting to me. I expect a mod will fix this once TESVCS comes out.

Comment: I sat by the entrance door, waited for her to go to her room, shot and then exited. They may have scripted the same reactions, but I did not have to listen to it (Even though all the kids cheer if you do listen to them). The guard standing RIGHT outside the door just thought I lost a sweet roll.

Comment: I did get bounty of 40 for assaulting.. no big deal but still, wonder how I could evade it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard weird, you aren't supposed to get any bounty at all, its entirely scripted.

Comment: I surely did.. right after getting outside a guard stopped me, I paid 80 gold and was done with it - no jail or anything. Maybe it's because the dialog options I chose?

Answer (score 6):

I had already done the thieves guild by this point and

> had the nightingale's special powers,

and so had the ability of invisibility (I assume any other spell or ability would work as well). I snuck in, was unnoticed, killed her and turned invisible before i was 'noticed' and left without the eye icon ever opening at all.

That's the best I think you can get - all the kids ran in and the help soon did also, but no one ever ran from me as if they were afraid or anything. As other people had said, it's unimportant and completely irrelevant, but it may be of note that this is how I did it. (I also never had anyone note that how I killed her was messy or anything either.)

Answer (score 4):

The help noticed me even when I was invisible, snuck into her room, closed the door and arrow'd her in the mouth. She came in and started running around like a nark. I think it's just scripted guys, no biggy anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Invisibility is the way to go, but you must remember you're invisible, not untouchable. Also, you must kill her in one hit. I did this by (no magic) sneaking into her room. It doesn't matter if you're seen on the way in, close the doors to her room, backstab for 30x Damage (shrouded gloves from the brotherhood + sneaking perk) and finally, 1 stolen bottle of invisibility that I drank as I sat in the corner while everybody ran into the room. I then simply walked past them without touching them and out the door. The script that caused the lady to run screaming that she yields and cannot best me never started.

Comment: Trying not to spoiler too much, but, how do you get the Shrouded Gloves without finishing this quest? As far as I know, there are a limited, fixed number of them and they all require events that are set in motion by killing Grelod. Not that you need the gloves, as she's a wimp.